# $env:PATH different for Windows Powershell and VSCode integrated Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using Windows 10.
The result of `$env:PATH` is different for Windows Powershell and VSCode integrated Powershell.
I need the  VSCode integrated Powershell to have the same path as Windows Powershell, how should I rectify this?

Comment: I see the same with a newly added MsBuildPath environment variable. It is in Windows Terminal (Windows Powershell/ pwsh / cmd). Inside VS Code it is in cmd, but not in Powershell, not even after restart Windows.

Comment: Curiously, mine happens with an MS MPI environment variable. Could something be happening related to the "M" character?

Answer (score 7):

Changing the user environment variables, reopening the terminal or reloading the window was not enough.

I had to exit and reopen VS Code manually.

This was on version *1.66.2*.

Edit: I see identical behavior on version *1.85.2* - released on 2024-01-18.

Answer (score 2):

the windows integrated powershell in VS code started to give me error like this for any command I typed, even dir and ls:

```
> ls : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '.C' does not exist. At
> line:1 char:1
> + ls dir : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '.C' does not exist. At line:1 char:1
> + dir
> + ~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.C:String) [], DriveNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound
```

The root cause was an extra . that was being appended in the PATH by VS Code which was not in the normal environment variables.

I figure it out by using "env" command from the another gitbash shell within visual studio!

The solution was to open the VS Code Setting.json and remove the code below which was containing some path:

```
> "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {},
> "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
>     "bash": {
>         "path": "bash",
>         "icon": "terminal-bash"
>     },
>     "zsh": {
>         "path": "zsh"
>     },
>     "fish": {
>         "path": "fish"
>     },
>     "tmux": {
>         "path": "tmux",
>         "icon": "terminal-tmux"
>     },
>     "pwsh": {
>         "path": "pwsh",
>         "icon": "terminal-powershell"
>     } }, "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {}, "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {},
```

After saving the settings.json and restarting once VS code all was back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was setting the environment variables for the USER and not the SYSTEM in windows 11.

I usually set variables like `JAVA_HOME` and reference them in my `PATH` like this `...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

This does not work in IntelliJ and VS Code, as they do not seem to be able to access the user variables. Once I set them as system variables, all is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just edited the PATH, try kill the terminal in VSCode and reopen the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Check the VSCode setting for "terminal.integrated.env.windows".

In my case, there was PATH setting so that caused the difference between Windows Powershell and VSCode integrated Powershell.

1. Delete PATH in "terminal.integrated.env.windows"
2. Restart VSCode

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today and had not `terminal.integrated.*` entries in my settings.json at all. Searching around the settings page though, I eventually found an entry for `Terminal > Integrated > Default Profile: Windows` which was set to a value of `null`. I changed this to `PowerShell` and restarted VSCode. After that, the path error was gone. I am still not certain where the `.C` was coming from. I could see when outputting my path that it was part of the very beginning of a full duplication of my `$PATH` at the end of my normal path. It is almost as though the PATH were set to something like `$PATH.$PATH`, but I really have no idea why. As long as I don't see too many negative implications of this fix though, I will stick with it.